# Disprove that if $f([-2, 2])$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Disprove that if $f([-2, 2])$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous

My counter example is $\begin{cases}
1 - x & \text{ if } -2 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 
2 - x & \text{ if } 1 < x \leq 2 
\end{cases}$

So in this case, $f([-2 ,2])$ is continuous on $[0, 3]$ but there's a jump discontinuity at $x = 1$. Would this be a valid counterexample?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  (Except you mean $f([-2,2])$ is an interval.  It equals $[0,3]$, it isn't "continuous on $[0,3]$".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a counterexample since $f([-2,2])=[0,3]$ and as you say $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$.